# How to address the object that has been Clicked but not the children inside it?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, programming-languages, click

inside a MouseEvent.CLICK function, I usually used e.target to address the movieClip that I clicked, but that only work with a movieClip that doesn't have any children (such as text and other symbols) inside. When it has children inside, the e.target return the child inside the Mc but not the Mc itself. The e.currentTarget didn't work, either; it returned [object MovieClip] but not the instance name of the Mc. Is there anyway I can fix it? 
thank you.

Comment: Do you need any user interaction in the children? If not, then you can disable interaction of children by setting mc.mouseChildren = false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the instance name you would need `e.currentTarget.name`.

Answer (score 2):

`e.target` = element that has been clicked.

`e.currentTarget` = element for that a listener has been registered.

Assuming a red box containing a blue box:

```
red.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK, redClick);
```

If you click the red box (outside the inner blue one):

`e.target` = red

`e.currentTarget` = red

If you click the blue box:

`e.target` = blue

`e.currentTarget` = red

---

To prevent your blue box dispatching click events you can disable mouse events for child elements:

```
red.mouseChildren = false;
```

If you then click the blue box:

`e.target` = red

`e.currentTarget` = red

Answer (score 1):

Set `mouseChildren` of the intended target to `false` to stop the events propagating into the MovieClip's children.